# Translate TeX documents with Deepl

Tags: latex, pandoc, deepl

When submitting a TeX file to Deepl, the result is not so good, but not so bad. Deepl does sometimes a good job with environements, macros, equations, etc. But my guess is that it has no idea what it actually does.
So, is there a nice way --with not too much work-- to parse TeX code in a way Deepl makes no mistakes?

Thank you for any help or experience,
--Fred

I have tried pandox TeX to Docx... and back. Not so good.

Comment: maybe try markdown?

Comment: Don't try `Markdown`. DeepL has no support for this format, the results will be roughly the same as `TeX`. Use `XML` or `HTML` as a temporary translation format. There is build in support for these two formats.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that machine translation is neural network-based, so you have no guarantees that your Latex tags will be ignored (they are essentially out-of-distribution unless you specifically train on that) and kept in the output.

Instead what you could do is transform your latex document to a temporary XML format and back, as DeepL supports ignore tags in XML, which ignore a certain part of a sentence during translation - this way you can guarantee your tags are ignored and kept in the output.
Basically you would need to wrap all Latex `\section{...}` etc in XML tags like this `<x>\section{...}</x>` and add `x` as an `ignoreTag` in your request.

[Docs for Ignore tags](https://developers.deepl.com/docs/xml-and-html-handling/html#disabling)